# activity recognition android stop when restart device

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I using activity recognition in service to check action of user. method ActivityRecognitionResult inside onStartCommand with START_STICKY. every thing work when device running, but when device restart activity recognition not restart. How I can make it work. please help me.

Comment: Please make it clear what you want to achieve here. I am guessing you want to start your service after device restart is that correct?

Comment: I'm not try restart service after device restart. so if I restart it I will receive DetectedActivity????

Comment: Any ideas of how this can be achieved?